# Astra Theme - Problem with sticky Add to cart

Tags: woocommerce

I have a problem with Sticky Add To Cart, i have Astra theme and Woocomm rce installed. Namely, after scrolling down the page, the bar appears, but when I scroll to the very top of the page, the bar does not hide. What could it be caused by? I have to refresh the page and only then Add to cart disappears. I noticed that if I make a popup in Elementor that pops up the same way as the Add to cart sticky (when scrolling), a similar problem occurs. The bar appears, but when moving to the top of the page, the bar does not disappear. Thanks in advance for your help! Because I’m starting to give up. The page address is: HTTPS://warmener.pl

Sticky Add to cart will dissapear when i scroll to the top.

Answer (score 0):

`sticky-add-to-cart.js`(unminified) and `sticky-add-to-cart.js`(minified) both files have a code line to get the button offset.

This is that line `document.querySelector( '.product .single_add_to_cart_button' ).offsetTop`

Right now, it's returning the value for some reason, maybe conflicting with elementor HTML tags or maybe because of some other reasons.

To fix the issue you'll have to use `getBoundingClientRect().top` instead of using `offsetTop`

so you'll have to modify both files and replace

```
document.querySelector( '.product .single_add_to_cart_button' ).offsetTop
```

with this next line:

```
document.querySelector( '.product .single_add_to_cart_button' ).getBoundingClientRect().top
```

It will solve your issue.

**Note: Purge/Clear the cache after file changes and force reload the page then test.**